# Change restangular url so that it doesn't go to a concatenation of localurl+serverurl?

Tags: rest, restangular

When I try to run the command:

```
return Restangular.one('me').get();
```

I get the following response

```
GET http://localhost:8100/serverurl:8666/api/v1/me 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I change so that all requests use the url below instead, and where in my code should I make this change?

```
http://serverurl:8666/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your base url

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://serverurl:8666/api/v1');
});
```

then everywhere inside app you can use

```
Restangular.one('me').get();
```

It will build GET request to http://serverurl:8666/api/v1/me